# present perfect to express accomplishment?

Tags: present-perfect

I have read this story about a man who has difficulty walking, but managed to climb  the stairs. For him this is quite an achievement.

He wrote: "I have been climbing stairs".

Could he have said: "I have climbed the stairs!" to express this accomplishment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly, if the accomplishment he had in mind was managing to *get to the top* of a *particular* flight of stairs, rather than being able to climb stairs at all.

For example, if you say:

> I have read a book!

you're happy that you've managed to *finish* reading a book, while if you say:

> I have been reading a book!

you're happy that you've been able to read for a while, even if you haven't necessarily finished the book in question.

Comment: Lets's say I climbed the stairs at 2 p.m.and it is now 5 p.m can I say "I have climbed the stairs today!" , because I am really proud or can I say this only shortly afterwards, when I have reached the top? –